# how to write new line to different streams properly

Tags: java

I have a collection of `OutputStream` (some are `socket.getOutputStream` , some are `FileOutputStream` -- these are changeable as long as it can still output to socket and file, and can be in the same collection.

When writing a line, I write - foreach outputStream:

```
line = "\n" + line + "\n";

out.write(line.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
out.flush();
```

The file looks fine, but the socket stream (there are multiple streams open at once via telnet) ends up looking like this (Example with 2 sockets):
[image]

Comment: It's possible your socket is expecting a different newline. By any chance is one system Windows and the other ***anything*** else? Also, [this](https://www.frischcode.com/2013/11/need-to-write-same-content-to-multiple.html) *might* help.

Comment: Windows cmd and Regular file in windows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not what you write to the stream but how the reader interprets this. For example, on Linux the newline character `\n` is interpreted as "go to the *beginning* of the next line". On Windows/DOS, it is interpreted only as "go to the next line". There you also need the `\r` (carriage return) character to indicate that you want to go to the beginning of the line.

Even on the same system, different programs may interpret things differently. For example, some text editors have switches to indicate whether to work with Windows or Unix style line breaks.

So depending on which code reads your stream, you may not be able to get consistent behavior. Unless you have all readers agree on which character(s) are used for "go to the beginning of the next line".

Comment: By the way, `System.lineSeparator()` may come in handy here. Or `System.getProperty("line.separator");`